# Apache proxy error failed to make connection to backend 127.0.0.1"

Tags: apache2, proxy, wordpress

I can't connect to my company website. it shows service unavailable.

> *Service Unavailable
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at [www.leangiap.com](http://www.leangiap.com) Port 44*

I tried to track using curl command and it returned 503 Service Unavailable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>503 Service Unavailable</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Service Unavailable</h1>
    <p>The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 47.254.196.130 Port 80</address>
</body>

</html>
```

I checked the apache error.log. It showed

```
apache proxy error failed to make connection to backend 127.0.0.1
```

Can anyone help??? Thanks

[image: screenful of log]

Answer (score 0):

This sort of error usually requires a multi-step fix with a little back and forth. The first thing you might want to do is add this to your virtual host configuration:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/ retry=0 timeout=5
```

Then restart Apache. This is not a complete solution, but the first part of one.

Comment: Cannot run this command. it shown Proxypass command not found..

Comment: @EricCheeKinSiew check your capitalization. It should be `ProxyPass` not `Proxypass`